# SonicWall NetExtender VPN Client looping on install: Warning 27852 Network component taking longer than expected

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I'm trying to setup a VPN so I can access my job's network at home. My boss told me to install SonicWall's NetExtender Global VPN Client. I launch the installer (64 bits for my Windows 10 64 bits system), and everything goes fine, until it starts to actually install the software on my computer. The process begins without any issues, but towards the end of the install a pop-up comes up with this message: "*Warning 27852. Network component taking longer than expected. Click OK to continue to wait or Cancel*". If I click OK, the install starts over, and the same warning comes up.

So I thought maybe the software has a problem, and I tried to install it on an other laptop (also x64 Windows 10). This time, the install successfully completed without any issues and I could connect to my job's network. So do you have any idea why I can't install the software on my main computer?

Comment: I have that client installed here and we run it on several Windows 10 machines at a client.  Try running DISM and SFC.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then (2) sfc /scannow . Restart when done and try installing Net Extender again.  Make sure there are no other VPN applications installed on your computer.

Comment: @John I tried it right now, and although sfc did allegedly repair some files, the issue stays the same. Also, my internet connection goes through my phone; with a mobile hotspot. Does this change anything?

Comment: Using a mobile hotspot does not change the installation success of Net Extender. If DISM and SFC have not helped you may need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link.  Use the second link on the page and Keep Everything at the appropriate point.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John Alright, I reinstalled my Windows. Still no luck. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you reinstalled Windows, Net Extender should install and work fine.

Comment: I assume the problem computer is Windows 10 PRO 64-bit.  That should work fine.

Comment: @John I did reinstall Windows, and it did not work. By the way, it is not a PRO version, but an education one (my school bought the liscence), but it should make no difference at all.

Comment: You may need to call Sonic Wall Support. I cannot find references beyond Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a winsock reset when the install lags and then immediately reboot while the install is still running.  It worked for me.